# How do I enable dropdown on hover in vue bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```
<div>
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
  <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
  <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
  <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

> The items should be shown when the dropdown button is hovered!

Comment: May be this could help https://codepen.io/antcook/pen/OboxbO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not as straighforward as I thought but here is one example on how to convert this bootstrap-dropdown into a hoverable dropdown.

```
<template>
  <div @mouseover="onOver" @mouseleave="onLeave">
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" ref="dropdown" class="m-md-2">
       <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      onOver() {
        this.$refs.dropdown.visible = true;
      },
      onLeave() {
        this.$refs.dropdown.visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The idea is to use v-on directives `mouseover` and `mouseleave` on a wrapper div (somehow the vue directive does not work on the b-vue component directly, but might be only me). Then use the event trigger to alter `dropdown.visible` state. Also in this example I make use of Vue's `$refs` to get hold of the dropdown within the script.

**Working example** https://codesandbox.io/s/2erqk

---

### Multiple Hover-Dropdowns

If you are planning on having this behaviour on multiple dropdowns at once, I would go into the trouble of creating a component out of it - incorporating the b-dropdown into a new component.

```
<template>
  <div @mouseover="onOver" @mouseleave="onLeave">
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" ref="dropdown" class="m-md-2">
      <slot></slot>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "b-dropdown-hover",
  methods: {
    onOver() {
      this.$refs.dropdown.visible = true;
    },
    onLeave() {
      this.$refs.dropdown.visible = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And then use it like this :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-dropdown-hover>
       <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown-hover>
    <b-dropdown-hover>
       <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
       <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
    </b-dropdown-hover>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

  import BDropdownHover from '@/components/BDropdownHover'

  export default {
    components : {
      BDropdownHover
    }
  }
</script>
```

But you also have to include all events and props that you need from `b-dropdown` into the new component. Here is a working example of that: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-elgamal-lol7h

Comment: Glad I could help @Abdan , will you mark my Answer as the correct one ?

Comment: If you want to use these directives on the b-dropdown component directly, you can add native modifier at the end (e.g. @mouseover.native = "onOver")

Comment: How do I implement this if I have more than one b-dropdown? Can I check it like if(this.$refs === dropdown1)?

Comment: how can I make it so that the b-dropdown-hover tag supports the same options as b-dropdown like dropright and dropleft?

Answer (score 2):

I made another solution for **multiple hover-dropdowns** based on the answer of @pascal-lamers.

If you don't want to create different components for this task, instead you would like to solve it in the same nav element, then you need to define multiple `ref`s and define the certain `ref` for your `onOver` and `onLeave` listeners.

```
<template>
    <div @mouseover="onOver('dropdown1')" @mouseleave="onLeave('dropdown1')">
        <b-dropdown id="dropdown-1" text="Dropdown Button" ref="dropdown1" class="m-md-2">
            <b-dropdown-item>First Action</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>Second Action</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>Third Action</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
    </div>
    <div @mouseover="onOver('dropdown2')" @mouseleave="onLeave('dropdown2')">
        <b-dropdown id="dropdown-2" text="Dropdown Button" ref="dropdown2" class="m-md-2">
            <b-dropdown-item>Fourth Action</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>Fifth Action</b-dropdown-item>
            <b-dropdown-item>Sixth Action</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-dropdown>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
    onOver(element) {
        this.$refs[element].visible = true;
    },
    onLeave(element) {
        this.$refs[element].visible = false;
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use v-b-hover in bootstrap-vue v2.5.0
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/directives/hover

Example from bootstrap-vue:

```
<template>
  <div v-b-hover="hoverHandler"> ... </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      hoverHandler(isHovered) {
        if (isHovered) {
          // Do something
        } else {
          // Do something else
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.