# How to open a select dropdown on hover using Bootstrap Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I need a way to trigger the `<select>` or `<b-form-select>` and display the list of dropdown options on mouse hover. Without using JQuery or any external plugin other than Vue.js.

Comment: This looks similair: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542120/how-do-i-enable-dropdown-on-hover-in-vue-bootstrap

Comment: @dominikjosch cannot get the same methods to work for the <b-form-select> component.

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding you want to show/hide the `<b-form-select>` on `mouseover` and `mouseleave` event. If Yes, I have few suggestions **:**

- Use a div as a wrapper which will trigger the `mouseover` and `mouseleave` events. We can directly trigger the mouse events by appending the `native` in the  itself but once it will hide, there will be no way to get the dropdown back on mouseover again.
- You can simply show/hide the dropdown via `v-show` directive. We can easily set the value from our mouse events.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      isVisible: true,
      options: [
        { value: null, text: 'Please select an option' },
        { value: 'a', text: 'This is First option' },
        { value: 'b', text: 'Selected Option' },
        { value: { C: '3PO' }, text: 'This is an option with object value' },
        { value: 'd', text: 'This one is disabled', disabled: true }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onOver() {
      this.isVisible = true;
    },
    onLeave() {
      this.isVisible = false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper-div {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper-div" @mouseover="onOver" @mouseleave="onLeave">
    <b-form-select
                   v-model="selected"
                   :options="options"
                   v-show="isVisible">
    </b-form-select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The effect of this solution is similar to opening the select by clicking on it (although, not the same ...)

```
<template>
  <select ref="mySelect" @mouseenter="hover(true)" @mouseleave="hover(false)" :size="size">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue';
export default {
  name: "Test",
  setup(){
    const mySelect = ref();
    const size = ref('0');
    return {mySelect, size}
  },
  methods: {
    hover(val) {
      this.size = val ? this.mySelect.length.toFixed(0) : '0';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```